# Inheritance between two classes in c++ using the same data members and functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to C++ programming and I want to create two classes that have the exact same data members and functions. Is it possible to create two inherited classes that have the same data members/functions instead of making several duplicate methods for each class. I'm making a c++ game based on zork and I want to create two items, weapons and fruits. Both will take in a name as a string and a value as a double. Do I create the header file as below:

```
    #ifndef ITEM_H_
    #define ITEM_H_

    #include <map>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Item {
    private:
        string description;
        string longDescription;
        float value;

    public:
        Item (string description, float inValue);
        Item (string description);
        string getShortDescription();
        string getLongDescription();
        float getValue();
        void setValue(float value);
    };
class Weapon:: public Item{
     };

    class Fruit:: public Item {
    };


    #endif /*ITEM_H_*/
```

How would I no go about creating the methods without duplicating them?

Comment: That's the whole point of inheritance. If a method is common to both weapons and fruit, put that method in the base class. It will then be inherited by, and usable in, both the weapon and fruit derived classes. As you seem to have done here.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I implement the method? Would it be Weapon::Item (string inDescription, float inValue) {
    description = inDescription;
    value = inValue;

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking about the *constructor*, not just any method. You will have to define constructors in both derived classes, as e.g. `Weapon(string description, float inValue) : Item(description, inValue) { }`. (Change `Weapon` to `Fruit` for the `Fruit` class's constructor.) You can't avoid "duplicating" this; both classes will need their own constructors since they need to call the base class's constructor.

Comment: also note: inheritance is done with one colon, not two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do nothing for now. Both `Weapon` and `Fruit` **are** `Item`s and contain all the members and methods that `Item` does.

Sooner or later, you'll want to specialize behaviour of child classes and the implementation of the method in the base class won't do it (if it's sensible to have an implementation in the first place). This is where polymorphism comes in. You'll make the method in the base class `virtual` and *override* it in the derived class:

```
class Item {
public:
    virtual void Use() = 0;  // pure virtual method
};

class Weapon : public Item {
public:
    virtual void Use() override
    {
        Fire();
    }
private:
    void Fire() { /* do something */ }
};
```

Now when you have a reference or a pointer to the base class and you call `Use` on it, it'll dispatch to the corresponding method in the derived class.

EDIT: There's no way around "duplicating" constructors. Each class needs at least one if it is ever to be instantiated. Since you declared `Item (string description, float inValue);` you need to define it as a member of `Item`, too:

```
Item (string description, float inValue)
    : description(description) // <-- avoid duplicating names of members in parameter list,
    , value(inValue)           // it does the right thing, but hurts readability
    { /* body empty */ }
```

If you need to call the constructor of the derived class with same parameters, you need to define another constructor and forward the arguments to the constructor of base class:

```
Weapon::Weapon(string desc, float val)
: Item(desc, val) { }
```

In C++11, there's a shortcut - you can inherit constructors and the compiler will generate these forwarding constructors for you:

```
class Weapon : public Item {
     using Item::Item;
};
```

There's (unfortunately, perhaps) no way to specify which constructors you want to inherit. It's all or nothing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So my header file is correct? Would the following method be somthing like this? Weapon::Item (string inDescription, float inValue) { description = inDescription; value = inValue;}

Comment: That would be a constructor you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call constructor of parent class to assign value to `description;` and `longDescription;` like

```
class Weapon:: public Item{
      Weapon(string description, float inValue):Item(description,inValue){}
      Weapon(string description):Item(description){}
 };
```